# Iframe Dynamic Content Resize

Tags: iframe, resize

I have an iframe that re-sizes its own content. The First time the iframe loades, the content re-sizes fine, but content not changing on subsequent resizing or page scrolling.

I have tried onresize,onmove...

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function autoIframe(frameId) {
        try {
            frame = document.getElementById(frameId);

            innerDoc = (frame.contentDocument) ? frame.contentDocument : frame.contentWindow.document;

            if (innerDoc == null) {
                // Google Chrome
                frame.height = document.all[frameId].clientHeight + document.all[frameId].offsetHeight + document.all[frameId].offsetTop;
            }
            else {

                objToResize = (frame.style) ? frame.style : frame;
                objToResize.height = (innerDoc.body.scrollHeight +200) + 'px';

                //document.getElementById("autosizeframe").style.height=(innerDoc.body.scrollHeight+18)+'px';
                //alert(frame.style.height+'-'+innerDoc.body.scrollHeight)
            }
        }

        catch (err) {
            document.getElementById("autosizeframe").style.height = '1600px';
            document.getElementById("autosizeframe").style.width = '1000px';
            //alert('Err: ' + err.message);
            window.status = err.message;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made an iframe auto resizer script too, years ago. Maybe it is helpful for you:
http://www.professorweb.de/javascript-ajax/iframe-hohe-an-dessen-inhalt-automatisch-anpassen-v2.html